# Java Generics - Bridge method?

Tags: java, generics

Something called the "bridge method" concept related to Java Generics made me stop at a point and think over it.

> Btw, I only know that it occurs at the
>   bytecode level and is not available
>   for us to use.

But I am eager to know the concept behind the "bridge method" used by the Java compiler.

What exactly happens behind the scenes and why it is used?

Any help with an example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't explain it clearer than this: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2010/03/java-bridge-methods-explained.html (which happens to be the 1st google result)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It's a method that allows a class extending a generic class or implementing a generic interface (with a concrete type parameter) to still be used as a raw type.

Imagine this:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
   public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
      //
   }
}
```

This can't be used in its raw form, passing two `Object`s to compare, because the types are compiled in to the compare method (contrary to what would happen were it a generic type parameter T, where the type would be erased).  So instead, behind the scenes, the compiler adds a "bridge method", which looks something like this (were it Java source):

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
   public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
      //
   }

   //THIS is a "bridge method"
   public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
      return compare((Integer)a, (Integer)b);
   }
}
```

The compiler protects access to the bridge method, enforcing that explicit calls directly to it result in a compile time error.  Now the class can be used in its raw form as well:

```
Object a = 5;
Object b = 6;

Comparator rawComp = new MyComparator();
int comp = rawComp.compare(a, b);
```

### Why else is it needed?

In addition to adding support for explicit use of raw types (which is mainly for backwards compatability) bridge methods are also required to support type erasure.  With type erasure, a method like this:

```
public <T> T max(List<T> list, Comparator<T> comp) {
   T biggestSoFar = list.get(0);
   for ( T t : list ) {
       if (comp.compare(t, biggestSoFar) > 0) {
          biggestSoFar = t;
       }
   }
   return biggestSoFar;
}
```

is actually compiled into bytecode compatible with this:

```
public Object max(List list, Comparator comp) {
   Object biggestSoFar = list.get(0);
   for ( Object  t : list ) {
       if (comp.compare(t, biggestSoFar) > 0) {  //IMPORTANT
          biggestSoFar = t;
       }
   }
   return biggestSoFar;
}
```

If the bridge method didn't exist and you passed a `List<Integer>` and a `MyComparator` to this function, the call at the line tagged `IMPORTANT` would fail since `MyComparator` would have no method called `compare` that takes two `Object`s...only one that takes two `Integer`s.

The FAQ below is a good read.

### See Also:

- [The Generics FAQ - What is a bridge method?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ102)
- [Java bridge methods explained](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2010/03/java-bridge-methods-explained.html) (thanks [@Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho))

Comment: Also for covariant return types even in the absence of generics.

Comment: @paulmurray: what is "equals(T o)"?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline can you clarify about covariant return type?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin is it only for comply old(before java 5) overriding rules?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Suppose you have a method `Object get()` and then override it in a subclass with, say, `String get()`. The JVM will only override exactly matching signatures including the return type. So javac creates a synthetic bridge method `Object get()` (a.k.a. `get()Ljava/lang/Object;`) with an implementation that calls `String get()` (a.k.a. `get()Ljava/lang/String;`). This has only been possible in source code since 1.5, and you can't target an earlier version of bytecode than the source code.

Comment: @Mark, is a bridge method in your example `public`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Yes, it is public as reported by `javap -v MyComparator.class`.  However, as I mentioned, the compiler prevents you from calling the bridge method directly on a parameterized type, so I'd say it's "public with a caveat".  If you look at the output of `javap`, you will see that the bridge method, despite having `ACC_PUBLIC`, has two additional flags: `ACC_BRIDGE` and `ACC_SYNTHETIC`.  This is what the compiler will look at use to prohibit access.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Note also that doesn't mean all bridge methods are public, just the one in my example.  If you were extending a class (and giving it a concrete type) with a protected generic method, and overrode it with a protected method, the bridge method would be protected to match.

Comment: @MarkPeters , what do you mean by: "This can't be used in its raw form, passing two Objects to compare, because the types are compiled in to the compare method", isn't `Integer` a concrete class already? how is it raw?

Comment: @juztcode: Meaning if you passed the `Comparator` to an existing raw function, say `max(Iterable items, Comparator cmp)` without the bridge method, calls within `max` to `comparator.compare(a, b)` would fail because `a` and `b` would have static type `Object`, and your comparator would have no method with the signature `int compare(Object, Object)`.

Comment: Considering "The compiler protects access to the bridge method, enforcing that explicit calls directly to it result in a compile time error.  " 

Interesting, how compiler protects access to the public bridge method? It seems calling it with wrong type would produce run-time exception, instead of compile-time error. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Answer (score 14):

If you want to understand why you need bridge method, you better understand what happens without it. Suppose there is no bridge method.

```
class A<T>{
  private T value;
  public void set(T newVal){
    value=newVal
  }
}

class B extends A<String>{
  public void set(String newVal){
    System.out.println(newVal);
    super.set(newVal);
  }
}
```

Notice that after erasure, method `set` in `A` became `public void set(Object newVal)` since there is no bound on Type parameter `T`. There is no method in class `B` the signature of which is the same as `set` in `A`. So there is no override. Hence, when something like this happened:

```
A a=new B();
a.set("Hello World!");
```

Polymorphism won't work here. Remember you need to override the method of parent class in child class so that you can use parent class var to trigger polymorphism.

What bridge method does is silently override the method in parent class with all the information from a method with the same name but a different signature. With the help of the bridge method, polymorphism worked. Though on the surface, you override the parent class method with a method of different signature.

Comment: I checked the whole internet but found your answer very easy and to the point. thanks million times.

Comment: @SunnyKhan That was me when I saw bridge method for the first time! Luckily I figured out how it works!

Answer (score 0):

It's insteresting to note that the compiler **infers** that `MyComparator`'s method:

```
public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {/* code */}
```

is trying to override `Comparator<T>`'s

```
public int compare(T a, T b);
```

from the declared type `Comparator<Integer>`. Otherwise, `MyComparator`'s `compare` would be treated by the compiler as an additional (overloading), and not overridding, method. And as such, would have no bridge method created for it.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by [this article](https://binarydoc.blogspot.com/2019/10/what-is-java-bridge-method-accbridge.html) and [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html), the key reason of the Java bridge method is [Type Erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) and [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Let's take the class [ArrayDeque](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.util.arraydeque) ([source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java)) as example, it contains a `clone()` method as bellow, because the class `ArrayDeque` implements the `Cloneable` interface so it must override the `Object.clone()` method.

```
public class ArrayDeque<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
                        implements Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
{

  public ArrayDeque<E> clone() {
    ....
  }
}
```

[image: UML Hierarchy Diagram of ArrayDeque]

But the problem is the return type of `ArrayDeque.clone()` is `ArrayDeque<E>`, and it did not match to the method signature defined in the parent `Object.clone()`, and in [Object.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java) the return type is `Object` instead.

```
public class Object {

    protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
}
```

The return type mismatch is a problem for **Polymorphism**. So in the compiled result file `ArrayDeque.class`, the Java compiler generated two `clone()` methods, one match the signature in the source code, the other one match to the signature in the parent class `Object.clone()`.

1. [clone()](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/method?classfilelocation=java.util.arraydeque&seq=58&methodname=clone) method returns `ArrayDeque<E>`, which is generated based on the corresponding source code
2. [clone()](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/method?classfilelocation=java.util.arraydeque&seq=62&methodname=clone) method returns `Object`, which is generated based on `Object.clone()`. **This method is doing nothing but calling the other `clone()` method.** And, this method is tagged as [ACC_BRIDGE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html), which indicates this method is generated by the compiler for the Bridge purpose.

[image: UML diagram generated based on ArrayDeque.class]