# JUnit's method count counts compareTo method twice. Why?

Tags: java, spring, generics, reflection, junit4

I am working on a Java Springframework project and using JUnit4 to test it.

My class implements Comparable and overrides the compareTo method.

In my test, when I do

```
@Test
Class<myClass> m = myClass.class;
Method[] methods = m.getDeclaredMethods();
assertEquals(5, methods.length);
```

This test fails **even though there are exactly 5 methods** in myClass. When I looked in  the Eclipse debugger, I see that the compareTo method gets called twice.

I can't find an explanation for this behavior. Why does this happen?

Comment: It would help if we saw the class file.  Feel free to omit the logic

Comment: added some tags that seem more relevant to me

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007357/java-generics-bridge-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler generates a bridge method for `compareTo()`

The mechanism is explained very well [in Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ: What is a bridge method?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ102):

> **What is a bridge method?**
>
> A synthetic method that the compiler
>   generates in the course of type
>   erasure.  It is sometimes needed when
>   a type extends or implements a
>   parameterized class or interface. The
>   compiler insert bridge methods in
>   subtypes of parameterized supertypes
>   to ensure that subtyping works as
>   expected.