# Multiple methods via reflection when implementing a method with generic return type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

When implementing a method with a generic return type and reflecting the declared methods on the implementing class, two methods are returned by the reflection API. Ex:

```
interface Referenceable<T> {
    T getReference();
}

class UUIDRef implements Referenceable<UUID> {
    public UUID getReference() {
      System.out.println("You called");
      return null;
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    UUIDRef ref = new UUIDRef();
    for (Method m : UUIDRef.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", m.getReturnType(), m.getName()));
      m.invoke(ref, null);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

`class java.util.UUID getReference
You called
class java.lang.Object getReference
You called`

Why am I getting two methods as having been declared on `UUIDRef`? Is there any way to accurately learn which of the two is the most refined, having actually been declared on `UUIDRef`?

Comment: Have you tried adding the @Override annotation to the implemented method?

Comment: I'm actually compiling against 1.5 where an @Override isn't allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support the covariant return type, [a bridge method must be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007357/java-generics-bridge-method) to be able to call the method in code that expects the declared return type.

In short, this bridge method is the method that would be called in the following scenario, where `T` is erased to `Object`:

```
public <T> T doSomething(Referenceable<T> obj) {
   return obj.getReference();
}
```

Use `m.isBridge()` to tell which is the bridge method.

Comment: Here is the reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Comment: That works. Thanks! (Waiting for timer to accept answer)