# How to just get the method in the implement class with a generic interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, interface

I have a generic interface and a class implementing it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

interface Interface<T> {
    void doSomething(T element);
}

class StringImpl implements Interface<String> {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String element) {
        System.out.println("StringImpl: doSomething");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(StringImpl.class.getDeclaredMethods()));
    }
}
```

And the result is

```
[public void com.ra.StringImpl.doSomething(java.lang.String), 
public void com.ra.StringImpl.doSomething(java.lang.Object)]
```

But in fact, I just want the implementing version:

```
public void com.ra.StringImpl.doSomething(java.lang.String)
```

Do you have any convient way to achieve it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Filter out [bridge methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007357/java-generics-bridge-method):

```
Method[] methods = Arrays.stream(StringImpl.class.getDeclaredMethods())
                         .filter(m -> !m.isBridge())
                         .toArray(Method[]::new);
```

Comment: Was about to answer with `!m.isSynthetic` but this is better.

Comment: @Mena yes this is better, not all synthetic methods are bridge

Comment: @Andrew btw there are only two places where the compiler will create bridge methods - covariant return types and generics

Comment: @Andrew I have checked the `modifiers` of the method in interface (and abstract class), which is 0x1041 => [synthetic, volatile, public]. But in my opinion, 0x1401 => [synthetic, abstract, public] is better. So I want to know why is `volatile` rather than `abstract`...

Comment: @UkonnRa `volatile` method?

Comment: @Eugene In fact, which means `Bridge`. `Bridge` and `Volatile` are both 0x40... I got it!