# java method return type is not actual type

Tags: java, methods, reflection, return-type

java method return type is not the actual type. For example,

```
public interface Foo<X extends TypeA> {
    public X hello();
}

public class Bar implements Foo<TypeB> {
    @Override
    public TypeB hello() {
       ...
    }
}

Method method = Bar.class.getDeclaredMethod("hello");
Class returnType = method.getReturnType();
```

returnType is `TypeA`, not `TypeB`.   `TypeB` is a subclass of `TypeA`.

How to get the actual return type of the method? It is `TypeB`, not `TypeA`.

### UPDATE

I used

```
Method[] methods = Bar.class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

and then iterate through the methods. The method returns the superclass. Verified that getDeclaredMethod("hello") do return the subclass type. Why are they different?

Comment: The X is bound by TypeA. How to use reflection in this case? thanks.

Comment: I get `TypeB` using JDK 11-ea+17. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_60"

Comment: BTW, I also get `TypeB` with JDK 10.0.1, and the same when using `getMethod` instead of `getDeclaredMethod`.

Comment: Just installed JDK 1.8.0_172 and I still get `TypeB`. ???

Comment: I get TypeB too with JDK8.

Comment: really? Let me debug it again.

Comment: If it is still happening, please provide an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because the code in the question doesn't even compile.

Comment: Just like to confirm that I also get the subclass as the return type on both JDK 1.8.0_172 and JDK 10.0.1

Comment: I used Method[] methods = Bar.class.getDeclaredMethods(); and then iterate through the methods. The method returns the superclass. Verified that getDeclaredMethod("hello") do return the subclass type. Why are they different?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007357/java-generics-bridge-method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you iterate through all declared methods with `getDeclaredMethods()` you will find two methods of similar signature:

- `TypeB hello()` (this is the one you expected)
- `TypeA hello()` (this is the one you talk of)

A look into the byte code reveals following entries:

```
public hello()Ltest/TypeB;

//... the bytecode for your method

public synthetic bridge hello()Ltest/TypeA;

//... bytecode that delegates to hello()Ltest/TypeB
```

This is an effect of the javac compiler, which introduces a synthetic bridging method `TypeA hello()` which only delegates to `TypeB hello()`.

The reason is that only a method of same signature can be called virtually. Since the interfaces signature is `TypeA hello()` any call to the interface will call `TypeA hello()` in the implementation. Yet your class `Bar` does not contain this method, but a replacement `TypeB hello()`. To resolve this issue javac chose to bridge the method (delegate it to the replacement). I think this will save them a lot of work at runtime.

So your problem does not occur from the method returning the wrong type, but your code returning the wrong method. If you iterate the methods, call `isSynthetic()` on them (true means that it is not the method of interest).

Comment: Do not understand the last sentence. I can see duplicate methods from debugging. How to ignore the methods defined in the interface and keep the methods declared by the class? Thanks.

Comment: The wrong method is `synthetic`. You can call `isSynthetic()` on the `Method` object. Every method returning `true` is not a method implemented in source code.