# why the java reflect mechanism create the both methods

Tags: java

That is my code.why the reflect api return both methods?

I defined an interface,like this:

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface Species<T> {
    T feed(List<String> numList);
}
```

the Animal is the implement class of Species:

```java
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Animal<T> implements Species<T> {


    private T t;

    @Override
    public T feed(List<String> numList) {
        return t;
    }

}
```

the Dog class is a child of Animal class:

```java
import java.util.List;


public class Dog extends Animal<String>{

    @Override
    public String feed(List<String> numList) {
        return "dog feed method";
    }
}
```

This is my test class,its:

```java
public class TypeTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<Dog> dogClass = Dog.class;
        Method[] declaredMethods = dogClass.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m:declaredMethods){
            System.out.println(m.getReturnType().getName());
        }

    }
}
```

the run output：

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.Object
```

check the variable declaredMethods

：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj2SA.png)

Answer (score 4):

`Dog` indeed has two declared `feed` methods. The one that returns `Object` is the [*bridge method*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007357/java-generics-bridge-method) for the one that returns `String`. The bridge method is generated by the compiler.

The implementation of the bridge method can be summarised as: just cast the parameters to the right types, and call your actual `String`-returning `feed`, and return what it returns.

A bridge method is needed because of type erasure. As far as the JVM is concerned, the interface method returns `Object`, so as an implementing class, `Dog` gotta have a method that returns `Object` too. The JVM can't magically find the `String`-returning method when you are calling `feed` through the `Animal` interface. It doesn't care about generics after all.