# How to explain the type of return value and parameter definition at sub class in a generic class hierarchy?

Tags: java, generics

Why are the return type and the parameter type at the pop and push methods respectively Child rather than Parent?

Suppose I have defined some classes as below:

```java
public class Parent {

}

public class Child extends Parent {

}

public class ParentStack<E extends Parent> {
    private Object[] elements;
    private int size = 0;

    public ParentStack() {
        elements = new Object[3];
    }

    public void push(E e) {
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    public E pop() {
        E result = (E) elements[size--];
        elements[size] = null;
        return result;
    }
}

public class ChildStack extends ParentStack<Child> {

    @Override
    public Child pop() {
        return super.pop();
    }

    @Override
    public void push(Child child) {
        super.push(child);
    }
}
```

The return and parameter types are Parent at ParentStack after the generic erase

```java
public class ParentStack {
    public void push(Parent e) {
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    public E pop() {
        Parent result = (Parent) elements[size--];
        elements[size] = null;
        return result;
    }
}
```

hence, theoretically, the ChildStack should define the types as Parent rather than Child, otherwise, these methods don't override the parent's method at all. How to explain this reasonally?

```java
public class ChildStack extends ParentStack<Child> {

    @Override
    public Parent pop() {
        return super.pop();
    }

    @Override
    public void push(Parent child) {
        super.push(child);
    }
}
```

Especially, if I clear the override methods defined at ChildStack, the signature API of ChildStack still are:

```java
public void push(Child child)
public Child pop()
```

Where do these methods come from?

```
        ChildStack cs = new ChildStack();
//        cs.push(Child);
//        Child c = cs.pop();
        ParentStack ps = cs;
//        ps.push(Parent);
//        Parent p = ps.pop();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may be aware, for `pop`, there is no problem at all. The return types don't have to exactly match to override a method. The method can return a more "specific" type than the method that it is overriding. The caller gets something that "is a" `Parent` no matter how `pop` is called.

---

As far as the Java *language* is concerned, generic types *exist*, and so the `push` in `ChildStack` does override that in `ParentStack`. See also the [overriding rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1). The overriding rules say that a method m1 overrides another method m2 if m1 and m2 *has the same signature*. And indeed `push(Child)` in `ChildStack` has the same signature as `push(T)` in `ParentStack`:

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) for what it means to have the same signature (emphasis mine):

> Two methods or constructors, `M` and `N`, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, **after adapting the formal parameter types of `N` to the type parameters of `M`, the same formal parameter types**.

After all, I hope you'd agree it is natural for `push(Child)` to override `push(T)` when `T` is `Child`, isn't it? The compiler does understand generics, so it can enforce those rules. It would be very inconvenient for the programmer otherwise, wouldn't it? They would have to write an extra method:

```
@Override
public void push(Parent p) {
    this.push((Child)p);
}
```

It is the Java Virtual Machine that doesn't understand generic types. As far as it is concerned, the `push` in `ParentStack` is `push(Parent)` and the `push(Child)` you wrote in `ChildStack` does not override it.

How does the compiler compile your code to something that the JVM understands, while also implementing the overriding rules? It secretly generates an extra `push(Parent)` *for you* (similar to the one I wrote above). This is known as a [bridge method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5007357/5133585). As far as the JVM is concerned, the bridge method overrides `ParentStack.push`, not the `push(Child)` method you wrote.

Comment: Thanks for your keen explanation, I have understood, however, I guess, my understanding is the codes you show above are generated by the compiler, and the type parameter in ParentStack class declaration is replaced with Child rather than Parent since the compiler should make the class definition follow the override rules. Additionally, this answer helps me a lot too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007357/java-generics-bridge-method

Comment: Hi, I unaccept because I found the explanation is not clear and understandable about the override, and hope the question can be answered continually. Why the type is Child at push in ChildStack rather than Parent, especially, if we clear the methods define in the ChildStack, the API of ChildStack stay the same with that before clearing, the latter one seems that the method 
```
    @Override
    public void push(Child child) 
```
has been defined at ParentStack.

Comment: @Maximillian Okay, let's forget about type erasure for a moment. `push` in `ParentStack` takes a `T`, and `T` has been replaced by `Child` in `ChildStack`'s declaration, since you said `class ChildStack extends ParentStack<Child>`. Therefore, I hope you agree that `push` in `ChildStack` naturally should take a `Child`.

Comment: @Maximillian Now lets introduce type erasure. Because of erasure, `push` in `ParentStack` takes a `Parent`, as far as the JVM is concerned. From its perspective, `push(Child)` in `ChildStack` does not override anything. But the designers of Java *really* want overriding to work *naturally* with generics. That is, they wanted to design it so that you don't need to write an extra `push(Parent)` method in `ChildStack` in order to override. They wanted `push(Child)` to override `push(T)` when `T` is `Child`. So they made the compiler generate this extra `push(Parent)` "helper" method.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, however, the description of "Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods." at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html  should not be totally correct. "The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound." seems to provide some hope to revise the description, but the meaning still is not clear at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6

Comment: @Maximillian I’m not sure why you think that section is relevant? Whether a method overrides another has nothing to do with erasure, as far as the language is concerned. The JVM use different rules than the language, which does not involve genetics, and I explained how that is handled by the compiler towards the end of answer.